# Jersey Rest Services + mySQL Database : No suitable driver found

Tags: java, mysql, rest, maven, jdbc

I'm developping Jersey services using a mySql Database. 
I have a maven project which gathers all of this and it works pretty well on my linux.
However a coworker is trying to use it under windows and accessing any services will fail with :

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://[hidden_ip_adress_for_topic]:3306/riskdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`

We are both using netbeans in which the mySQLConnector is included (according to my invastigations).

Our poject is made of 2 modules : Services and Library. In the library there is all the stuff for database managment. And If I try the library's functions, it works well, I can get data from database ! But as soon as I run Glassfish, An internal error 500 with "driver not found" appears.

Maybe I didn't understand what is the SQL-connector...

Have you got any hint for me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either copy driver (the jar file downloaded from mysql website) just like it is instructed [here](https://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-setup-a-jdbc-connection-in-glassfish/) or properly treat your driver as a maven dependency added to the module interacting with the database:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I would suggest second option because of project portability. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer !
I already had the maven dependency in the module.
But I tried to put it in each POM's module. It worked...
It seems that it wasn't in the good module. 
I don't understand why it worked on linux.

Comment: Actually, I had version 6.0.2 at the good location but this version doesn't work on windows. Don't know why. I used the lastest of version 5.X and it works.